# jquery toggleClass children on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to toggle class for children in an element on hover. But I'm doing something wrong.. can't figure out what

Let's say I have this svg in html:

```
<svg id="toplogo" height="200" width="200" alt="" viewBox="0 0 492.69 617.696">
<circle class="fill" fill="#00bbff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="32" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="246.16" cy="222.62" r="206.843"/>
</svg>
```

And this jquery (inside document ready):

```
$("#toplogo").hover(function() {

$(this).children('.fill').toggleClass('hoverfill');

});
```

And this css:

```
.hoverfill {
    fill: #ff0000;
}
```

Nothing happens. The fill is not changed

**See it on http://jsfiddle.net/k4djq/1/**

But it works when I test with

```
$("#toplogo").hover(function() {

$(this).children('.defaultstroke').css("fill","#ff0000");

});
```

Comment: not sure why it doesn't work, but do you need jquery here? .fill:hover {
 fill: #ff0000;
}

Comment: Hmm strange. It seems to be a browser issue.. Does not work here on Chrome, Firefox, IE11 or Opera. But Safari is fine. EDIT: oh you edited your comment (or maybe it was deleted)

Comment: @nevermind I tried that.. but when using hover on the circle, the hover point itself seems to be the stroke circle (very narrow), and not the entire image. It must be the entire image (#toplogo). Any way to achieve this with css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

Better use css to get hover/unhover effect

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k4djq/17/)**

```
#toplogo:hover circle {
    fill: #ff0000;
}
```

---

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k4djq/5/)**

Try `.attr()`, `.add/toggleClass()` does not work with SVG,

```
$("#toplogo").hover(function() {

    $(this).children('.fill').attr('class','hoverfill');

});
```

Also the `circle` has attribute as fill, so you can use :

```
$(this).children('.fill').attr('fill','#ff0000');
```

---

**[Reference](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/addclass-function-on-a-svg-circle-doesnt-work)** :

> jQuery is designed to work with the HTML DOM (and XML DOM). However
>   the SVG DOM is slightly different and not all jQuery functions work
>   correctly.

Some plugins are available to make it work :

http://keith-wood.name/svg.html#dom

Comment: This is working. So far so good :) How do I un-hover to the previous default value, without setting it? I guess it's a matter of removing the class hoverfill again, no?

Comment: but again remove class won't work there. I guess you have to set it.

Comment: @mowgli, updated with your problem, checked my answer. **Update** section

Comment: That seems to be working fine.. But the thing is.. my real logo has multiple elements, and more than just the circle must change on hover. Is that possible using css alone?

Comment: Maybe I should use jquery.. and retrieve the default color value on the elements, and then set it one hover:out

Comment: there is no hover:out effect on circle, Thats the problem why I used css. You can apply multiple elements in css

Comment: How would I do that? Just a small hint would be nice, then I can google it

Comment: Just add `#toplogo:hover yourelement{ cssproperty : value }`

Comment: I need to change color on multiple elements in the logo svg on hover (on anything on the logo). I think I need jquery for this

Comment: You can use `.css()` from jquery for other elements and css just for `circle`

Comment: I altered my logo in illustrator, so some parts are now combined.. So now I can easily make that hover effect in CSS. CSS is always the way, if possible! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use `attr` instead of `class` cause the color comes from the attr `fill`

**js**

```
$("#toplogo").on("mouseenter mouseleave", 
             function(e){
                 var color = $("#orgColor").attr("color");
                 if(e.type == "mouseenter"){
                     $(this).children('.fill').attr("fill", "blue");
                 }
                 else if(e.type == "mouseleave"){
                     $(this).children('.fill').attr("fill", color);
                 }
```

});

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4djq/24/)

Also i add a hidden input in your html to keep the original color. Check the fiddle.

Comment: How do I un-hover to the previous default value, without setting it?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, every time a script is used to edit an element's style, it's always best to try doing it straight from the source.

Try this:

Remove the function completely and simply add the following CSS selector

```
#toplogo:hover .fill { fill: #ff0000; }
```

This will do exactly what you want and remove the need to write some code.

Comment: Can I target multiple elements with this?

Comment: Yes. You are only limited by the selectors options, and even without using the new CSS3 options you still have plenty of, well, options

Comment: This is also the correct answer, but can't accept more than one. Thanks